# how to use: before in css in js inside the materialui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to apply a before in the appbar. What is going wrong with this code?

```
import { styled } from "@material-ui/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";

export const MyCustomAppBar = styled(AppBar)({
  background:
    "-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(155,155,155,1) 0%, rgba(214,214,214,0.48) 100%)",
  background:
    "-webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(155,155,155,1) 0%,rgba(214,214,214,0.48) 100%)",
  background:
    "linear-gradient(to right, rgba(155,155,155,1) 0%,rgba(214,214,214,0.48) 100%)",

  root: {
    "&::before": {
      content: "a",
      borderRadius: "100%",
      width: "150%",
      marginTop: "-40px",
      height: "121px",
      marginLeft: "-25%"
    }
  }
});
```

I tried in several ways to apply the before but it seems to me some limitation

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe (but not certain) that the styled-components syntax supports overriding specific classes (e.g. `root`) within the component, but you can do the following:

```
export const MyCustomAppBar = styled(AppBar)({
  background:
    "-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(155,155,155,1) 0%, rgba(214,214,214,0.48) 100%)",
  background:
    "-webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(155,155,155,1) 0%,rgba(214,214,214,0.48) 100%)",
  background:
    "linear-gradient(to right, rgba(155,155,155,1) 0%,rgba(214,214,214,0.48) 100%)",

  "&::before": {
    content: '"hello"'
  }
});
```

Though I don't think the first two "background" entries are doing anything -- I'm pretty sure they will be trumped by the third.

I wasn't clear on the effect you were trying to achieve with your "before" so I changed the content just to more easily show that the syntax works.

[image: Edit 03mrk21oww]